# Oracle combine two rows into one

Tags: sql, oracle, row, union

I have a result like this:

```
15.04.13    5   Doe, John   2431    null    null 46 560 0   null    0
15.04.13    5   Doe, John   2431    paid    525  0  0   585 null    60
```

this is the result of a union of two queries.

What I need is one row per day and person.

What I'm looking for is a way to combine these two rows to something like

```
15.04.13    5   Doe, John   2431    paid    525  46 560 585 null    60
```

Ok lets say I get an result like that:

```
15.04.13    5   Doe, John   2431    null        null 46 560 null null    0
15.04.13    5   Doe, John   2431    not paid    323  0  0   452  null    55
15.04.13    5   Doe, John   2431    paid        525  0  0   585  null    60
```

I need the second and third row and will match the 46 and the 560 from the first row to all rows below.

In that case the group by an max() won't work.
How can I solve this ?

Comment: You are going to need to add a lot more detail to this question. Columns headers would be a good start. Also, what are the business rules for combining the data? For example, the column with 560 and 0 results in 560, is that a SUM or a MAX?
Withouth knowing hte business rules required, it is going to be very difficult for anyone here to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a job for [GROUP BY](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/group_order.php)

```
select some_date
,      some_id
,      some_name
,      some_number
,      max(paid) paid
,      max(amount) amount
,      max(etc) etc
from   some_table
group by some_date
,      some_id
,      some_name
,      some_number
```

Comment: yep I guess thats bassically it. I tried this already but forgott some columns. So the result wasn't exactly the one I was looking for.